# visudo crashing on making changes

Tags: visudo

I am attempting to add an entry to `visudo`:

```
admin ALL=(ALL) /bin/kill
```

I have attempted to make changes to this in the past but crashed the visudo file.  Can someone assist in telling me where exactly the command above should be placed?

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following on a terminal:

```
sudo visudo
```

And then add the line `admin ALL=(ALL) /bin/kill` at the end of the file just opened.
To save and exit, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then `:x`.

If you ever happen to break your `sudo` command(actually a user), you should boot your machine in "recovery mode" and then drop to root in a writable filesystem and then change the above mentioned file(the file that gets modified by the above command is `/etc/sudoers`).